# Как на java определить наличие слова в строке?

Tags: android, java

Как на java(android) определить наличие слова в строке?
Например есть строка:

```
String str = "наличие слова в строке";
```

Я ввожу "слов" и если оно есть, то функция возвращает true, иначе false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
boolean checkForWord(String line, String word){
            return line.contains(word);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

См.[String.contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
str.contains("слов")
```